# Grammar confusion with use of 頼みてえ

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, contractions

I came across this sentence:

> ちょうどいい！　**頼【たの】みてえ**事【こと】がある！

My translation:

> Just in time! I have a favor to ask!

I'm not really sure what grammar rule is being applied to the bold part. It seems like the base verb being used here is `頼む` but the て-form of this verb is `頼んで`, so I am confused as to how `頼む` transformed into `頼みてえ`

What grammar rule(s) are actually going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just 頼みたい with the very common sound change /ai/ -> /ee/.